# Joint entropy of cards color

Tags: information-theory, entropy

If we have 52 cards, 26 red and 26 black, and we take out one card at a time (and don't return it).
Xi is the color of the card i.
What is H(X1,X2,X3...X52)?

I tried with H(X1,X2,X3) or I(X1,X2,X3) to see if any parameters gets canceled by one another, but couldn't find any combinations that's "easy to calculate".

Answer (score 0):

A simple argument should allow you to assert that $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{52})$ is unifom on $\binom{52}{26}$ issues, therefore its entropy is easy to compute.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what you mean. What's the simple argument to assert that?

Comment: In your experience, all permutations of your 52 cards can appear uniformely, so with probability 1 over 52!. If you consider any fixed sequence of R and B, with 26 B and 26 R (for exemple (B,B,R,R,B,B,...B,B,R,R)), it will be the image of 26!x26! permutations of the cards. It will appears with probability 1 over 26 choose 52.